# how to handle java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

Hi everyone I am really stuck, I keep getting the `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I tried to handle it in every possible place but I am not doing it successfully. It is homework.If you can look and give some feedback about the `java.lang.NullPointerException` it would be great.
The exception occurs in `Captain.handleProblem()`  and `MalfucntionHandler.proccessMalfunction()`

```
    public abstract class MalfunctionHandler 
    {

        MalfunctionHandler next;
        /**
         * severity is a type of Severity 
         */
        Severity severity;

        /**
         * @param description describes the severity of the problem
         */
        String description;


        /**
         * @param f file object  that refers to the log-silver.txt
         */
        File f = new File("log-silver.txt");

        MalfunctionHandler(Severity severity)
        {
                this.severity = severity;
        }
         public String getDescription()
        {
            if(description == null)
            {
                description = "No description available. Probably serious.";
            }
            return description;
        }

        final protected void processMalfunction(Malfunction malfunction)
        {
            if (this.severity == malfunction.getSeverity())
            {
               handleProblem();
            }
            else
            {
    //            if(malfunction == null)
                next.processMalfunction(malfunction);
            }
        }
        final protected void addHandler(MalfunctionHandler next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }
        abstract void handleProblem();

        public Severity getSeverity() 
        {
            return severity;
        }
    }


public class Malfunction 
{
    /**
     * severity is a type of Severity 
     */
    Severity severity;

    /**
     * @param description describes the severity of the problem
     */
    String description;

    Malfunction(Severity severity, String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.severity = severity;
    }

    public Severity getSeverity() 
    {
        return severity;
    }

     public String getDescription()
    {
        if(description == null)
        {
            description = "No description available. Probably serious.";
        }

        return description;
    }
}

public enum Severity 
{
     TRIVIAL, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
}

public class SpaceMonkey extends MalfunctionHandler {

    MalfunctionHandler malfunction;

    SpaceMonkey(Severity severity)
    {
       super(severity);
    }
    @Override
    void handleProblem() 
    {
        if(malfunction.getDescription() == null)
        {
            description = "No description available. Probably serious.";
        }
           FileUtility.writeFile(f, malfunction.getDescription()); 
           FileUtility.writeFile(f, "---> Space monkey assigned to problem.");
    }
}

public class ServiceRobot extends MalfunctionHandler {


     MalfunctionHandler malfunction;

    ServiceRobot(Severity severity)
    {
        super(severity);
    }
    void handleProblem() 

    {
       if(malfunction.getDescription() == null)
        {
            description = "No description available. Probably serious.";
        }
           FileUtility.writeFile(f, malfunction.getDescription());
           FileUtility.writeFile(f, "---> Service Robot assigned to problem.");
    }

}

public class Engineer extends MalfunctionHandler
{

     MalfunctionHandler malfunction;

    Engineer(Severity severity)
    {
        super(severity);

    }

    void handleProblem() 
    {
         if(malfunction.getDescription() == null)
        {
            description = "No description available. Probably serious.";
        }
          FileUtility.writeFile(f, malfunction.getDescription());
           FileUtility.writeFile(f, "---> Engineer assigned to problem.");
    }

}

public class Captain extends MalfunctionHandler
{
     MalfunctionHandler malfunction ;

    Captain(Severity severity)
    {
        super(severity);
    }

    @Override
   void handleProblem( ) 
    {
        if(malfunction.getDescription() == null)
        {
            description = "No description available. Probably serious.";
        }
           FileUtility.writeFile(f, malfunction.getDescription());
           FileUtility.writeFile(f, "---> Captain assigned to problem.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of your NPE?

Comment: post all the error message you've got

Comment: just eddited it in the beggining before the code

Comment: You never initialise `MalfunctionHandler malfunction` in the `Captain` class, so it is null and `malfunction.getDescription()` will throw a NPE - there might be other NPE in your code.

Comment: @assylias.. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Well, MalfunctionHandler is an abstract class, I though the abstract classes in java can't be initialised

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter - quite right, which means that you need to initialise a *subclass* of MalfunctionHandler and use that instead

Comment: And if I  do  MalfunctionHandler malfunction = Captain(severity); and the it is giving java.lang.stackoverflowerror

Comment: im curious, what exactly do you expect to be in the aptly named field 'malfunction'

Comment: and the error this time is in the SpaceMonkey MalfunctionHandler malfunction = new SpaceMonkey(severity); and when in the constructor  of spaceMonkey super(severity) and in the MalfunctionHandler  File f = new File("log-silver.txt");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 if(malfunction.getDescription() == null)
```

you never initialized your **MalfunctionHandler** object in class **SpaceMonkey** and trying to call its **getDescription()** method in **handleProblem** method. In java Objects get default value as null your  MalfunctionHandler malfunction; is null here and you are trying to access its method on null.

as your MalfunctionHandler is an abstract class, initialize it with its sub class (SpaceMonkey)

```
 MalfunctionHandler malfunction; = new SpaceMonkey(Severity);
```

Comment: @RohitJain  MalfunctionHandler is an abstract class not Malfunction :)

Comment: Sorry I mean `MalfunctionHandler`. malfunction is a reference of that class.

Comment: @RohitJain no worries, BTW you rock mahn .. your answers are pretty informative .. :)

Comment: But in my code it is not Malfunction malfunction and it is MalfunctionHandler malfunction

Answer (score 2):

Malfunction object ***is not initialized, its just declared in the Captain class.***

Also its not advisable to catch NullPointerExceptions. Instead you should validate and give checks in your code so that such exceptions won't be produced.

Answer (score 2):

By default object type of instance variable are null

```
 MalfunctionHandler malfunction;
```

and

```
 MalfunctionHandler malfunction = null;
```

are same. Your classes has this problem

here `if(malfunction.getDescription() == null)`  and malfunction is null so you are getting NPE here.